# Can we implement copy to clipboard in AMP stories?

Tags: amp-story

AMP stories is a good way to show content. Some of the elements available in AMP are very cool. Can we implement copy to clipboard in AMP stories?

For example, I want to show the user a text like **Copy this coupon and apply**. And when the user presses that text, the coupon is copied.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in AMP stories.  You can file it as a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A+Feature+Request&template=feature_request.md&title=)

Comment: Thank you Jon for clarifying this.